# Calculating BMI in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
   int userAgeYears = 0;
   int userAgeDays  = 0;
   int userWeight = 0;
   int userHeight = 0;
   int BMI;
   printf("Enter your age in years: \n");
   scanf("%d", &userAgeYears);
   userAgeDays = userAgeYears * 365;
   printf("Enter your weight in pounds: \n");
   scanf("%d", &userWeight);
   printf("Enter your height in inches: \n");
   scanf("%d", &userHeight);
   BMI = ((userWeight/(userHeight * userHeight)) * 703);
   printf("You are %d days old.\n", userAgeDays);
   printf("Your BMI is: %d\n", BMI);
    return 0;
}
```

// My result for BMI keeps computing to 0.

Am I doing anything incorrect.

Comment: Please format your code .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There's the "edit" field underneath your question. Use it to remove all the wrong things in your question. It's totally illegible like this. Why didn't you at least have *one* look at the preview?

Comment: A guide on how to format code in markdown is here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Hint: don't use `int`s to calculate floating point results.

Comment: `userWeight/` --> `(double)userWeight/`

Comment: Another hint: Leap years have 366 days.

Comment: Use all variables as type `double` .

Answer (score 5):

try doing it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
   int userAgeYears = 0;
   long userAgeDays  = 0;
   int userWeight = 0;
   int userHeight = 0;
   double BMI;

   printf( "Enter your age in years: \n" );
   scanf( "%d", &userAgeYears );
   userAgeDays = userAgeYears * 365;
   printf( "Enter your weight in pounds: \n" );
   scanf( "%d", &userWeight );
   printf( "Enter your height in inches: \n" );
   scanf( "%d", &userHeight );

   BMI = ( userWeight / (double)(userHeight * userHeight) ) * 703;

   printf( "You are %ld days old.\n", userAgeDays );
   printf( "Your BMI is: %02f\n", BMI );

   return 0;
}
```

this happened because you defined all the variables as integers, and it rounded the answer of `userWeight/(UserHeight*UserHeight)` to 0

Comment: In the absence of a **strong** reason otherwise, prefer `double` to `float`

Comment: I'll change it, but can you briefly explain what is a **strong** reason?

Comment: I can only think of one as of this moment: your teacher said she'd give you a bad grade for using `double` and no amount of discussion made her change her mind. *`double` is faster than `float`, the internal calculations with `float` require a conversion to `double` then back to `float`, unadorned floating point constants (such as `3.14159`) are of type `double`, `float` values corresponding to `...` in function parameters are converted to `double`, many functions using floating-point values require a sufix of `f` when dealing with `float` (eg `sinf()`), ...*

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common error in C/C++. The result of dividing two integers is an integer unless you force it to another type, so the division value will be truncated at each step.

Since the division of weight by height squared is done before you multiply by the 703 conversion factor, it is truncated to zero. (There are values of weight and height where it won't be zero, but the calculations will still be inaccurate due to the loss of precision.)

The best thing to do is to cast to double or read in the original values as doubles. As long as one operator is a float or double, then the truncation won't occur.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
BMI = ((userWeight/(userHeight * userHeight)) * 703);
```

is using integer math.  in integer math if the divisor is larger than the dividend, the result is always 0.   Suggest:

```
BMI = (( (float)(userWeight) /(userHeight * userHeight)) * 703);
```

Then all the values will be converted to 'float' the result calculated, and the 'floor()' value assigned to 'BMI'